# Should I throw in current method or let the later method throw it

Tags: c#, exception, throw

I am having a hard time when it comes to *good* design.
I am unsure if I should let a later method throw an exception or if I should throw it myself. 
Thing is:
 **The type of the Exception changes based on the method being called**. In the later method it might be an InvalidOperation but in the current method an ArgumentException may better fit.

Now should I really perform all the checks in order to throw the correct type of exception or should I let the deeper method throw the incorrect type of exception?

Consider this:

```
private bool _canWaste = false;



/// <summary>
///    Runs around and wastes something.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
///     Thrown when <paramref name="CanPower"/> is false.
/// </exception>
public void Run(bool CanWaste) {
   _canWaste = CanWaste;
   // <- Should I check if we can waste and throw an ArgumentException here or 
   //    throw the 'wrong' type later in Waste?
   Waste();
}



/// <summary>
///    Wastes something.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
///     Thrown when we cannot waste.
/// </exception>
private void Waste() {
   if(!_canWaste) throw new InvalidOperationException("We cannot waste.");
   /* ... */
}
```

This is a simple example (that does not make sense) where it would be easly done. 
But of course, there are methods where the evaluation is much harder.

Another option would be to catch the exception and throw a new of the correct type. 
But I guess that would hit performance and register some uncool stuff in the ouput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not throw *or let the code throw* incorrect type exception, that doesn't help any one. If you get an invalid argument throw `InvalidArgumentException`, otherwise let the exception bubble up to the caller from the library.

From the description, it sounds like *that* you are trying to control the execution flow through exceptions. Do not do that. Exceptions are "Exceptions", use them when there are exceptional scenarios that you can't avoid.

There is no point in catching and re-throwing that exception, unless you want to reset the stack trace *yourself*.

Comment: But if the correctness of an argument can only be validated by calling a method that throws an exception if the argument was invalid. Should i catch that and throw an invalidargumentexception?

Comment: @NoelWidmer, consider a simpler example, suppose you are getting a string parameter for `DateTime`, that has to be in a specific format, When you try to parse your *string* DateTime to `DateTime` object using `DateTime.ParseExact` and you get end up with a invalid string format exception, In that case you can you can catch exception occurred during parsing and return an `InvalidArugmentException`  to the client. If your scenario is similar to that, then sure, catch `InvalidOperationException` and then throw `InvalidArgumentException`

Comment: In Addition to above ^^, if the sole purpose of your method is to verify argument, it should be named likely, and may return a bool indicating if the argument is valid or not, instead of throwing exception, just making the intent more explicit, and code more readable, IMO.

Comment: That is useful, thanks :) Also the exec flow is good reminder. And remember that this is a 'stupid' example and that I am not really trying to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should always throw as fast as possible. On that way you prevent that code is executed in an invalid state which could cause major issues(f.e. you delete all records instead of one because the filter was incorrect).

Also, if you throw quickly you ensure that the caller gets the most meaningful message.

```
public void Run(bool CanWaste)
{
    if(!CanWaste)
        throw new ArgumentException("CanWaste must be true", "CanWaste");
    Waste();
    // ...
}
```

However, if you don't know if the argument is invalid and the determination is expensive(f.e. you need to execute it) then let the deeper method throw.
You could handle the `InvalidOperationException` in the calling method:

```
public void Run(bool CanWaste)
{
    _canWaste = CanWaste;

    try
    {
        Waste();
    }catch(InvalidOperationException ioe)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("CanWaste must be true", "CanWaste", ioe);
    }
}
```

Of course in this case it's easy to determine if the argument is valid. It's also not the best example since a `bool` paramater that can only be `true` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well that is what is confusing me. Because the argument is not really invalid, not even in the current method. It's just some operation that relies on the validity of some value, which happens to be my argument. But I guess it makes the sense to inform that the arg was invalid.

Comment: @NoelWidmer: but you call `Waste` first which doesn't like if `_canWaste == false`, so actually it _is_ already invalid in this method or it's incorrect to throw an `InvalidOperatonException` in `Waste`.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thx for clearing this up for me.